# Passing object of derived class to base class

Tags: c++, inheritance

Hi I have a derived class and I want to pass the pointer of the derived class object to the base class.
I am getting segmentation fault while running the code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {
    public:
    virtual void x() = 0;
    A* a;
};

class B: public A {
public:

  B(A* x) {
    a = x;
  }

 void x () {}

};

class C: public B {
    public:
    C() : B(new C) { } 
};

int main() {
    C c;
    return 0;
}
```

Can someone help me suggest a way to achieve this or help me in fixing the code.

Comment: `C() : B(new C)` ? You do understand that `new C` creates new `C` object, that then calls `C` constructor, that then creates `new C`, that then calls `C` constructor, that then ..

Comment: pretty sure you have infinite recursion, creating a `C` requires making a `new C` which requires making a `new C` ... you get the point

Comment: I want to call base class constructor and base the object pointer of derived class

Comment: May I ask what your final application is?

Comment: why do you think you need it?

Comment: Unrelated but always put a virtual destructor in your base class

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to pass a pointer to current object. This is what `this` is for.

```
C() : B(this) { }
```

Comment: I am a bit new to C++. Don't I need to allocate space to  the class pointer ?

Comment: @user2033594 No you don't. `this` just points to the object `C` that you've created. But I don't see the benefit of storing it in the base class, as you simply can use `this` in the base class.